# React-native Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNI18n.locale')

Tags: node.js, react-native

On every react-native project I try and build (from start kits, to an empty project) the RNI18n error.

None of rht following worked

- I get no errors in the console.
- I have tried with a fresh (unmodified) react-starter repo
- I uninstalled (then re-installed) react native (via npm)
- I also posted on their repo without an answer
- I tried running from the cmd "react-native run-ios" and from the .xcodeproj file

I am on OSX. Non-react app's work fine.

The error:

```
2016-09-06 21:48:56.897 [warn][tid:main][RCTEventEmitter.m:54] Sending `websocketFailed` with no listeners registered.
2016-09-06 21:48:56.991 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNI18n.locale')
2016-09-06 21:48:56.994 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNI18n.locale')
2016-09-06 21:48:57.008 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: The stack is null
2016-09-06 21:48:57.064 [error][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
2016-09-06 21:48:57.066 [fatal][tid:com.facebook.react.RCTExceptionsManagerQueue] Unhandled JS Exception: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module.
2016-09-06 21:48:57.072 [warn][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] Unable to symbolicate stack trace: The stack is null
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reboot was required of my PC. This may be a bug in the current (latest) version (0.39)

Comment: Thank you, this is the only thing that worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems on *testing* with Mocha. But I sent PR and it was approved a while ago (https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n/blob/master/index.js)

There's a chance that your links / libraries on iOS is not properly set. If `rnpm link` has failed for some reason, maybe you want to read about manual setup (https://github.com/AlexanderZaytsev/react-native-i18n#manual-setup)

Comment: How would I know if "rnpm link" has failed? I followed your link guide (the part with xcode) however I have no (Linkn Binary With Library files showing). Here is a screenshot- http://i.imgur.com/FWE16Nw.jpg

Comment: Stange. A reboot was all that was required. REBOOT

Answer (score 1):

First make sure to install the React i18n package:

npm install react-native-i18n --save

Then you need to add the library in xcode, I assume that's what you are missing, here is how:

[image]

Right click on Libraries -> Add Files to "Your Project", then search in your node-modules, your react-native-i18n/ios/RNI18n.xcodeproj

[image]

Then go to Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries, and select the library you just added.

[image]

Something like this (I don't have it on my list because I already added ;-) )

[image]

I hope it helps, and good luck!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try lowering the version of i18n. This worked for me.